# Can you curry a function with varargs in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying

I was thinking about how to go about currying a method with varargs, and I realized that I don't even have an intuition for how one would go about doing it.  Ideally, it would be something that would let you start using it whenever you liked, and then end it with an iterable.

```
def concat(strs: String*) = strs.mkString

val curriedConcat = concat.curry

curriedConcat("OK")("hello", "world")("welcome")(Seq(): _*)
```

Is there support for this in scala?  I couldn't figure out how to do anything more than bind it to a function of length N and then curry that.

Comment: There is no such thing as "function with varargs" in scala. There are only such `methods`.

Comment: I don't think that is correct.  I am using a method in my example, but I could be using a function.  Here is a simple hack to construct one:

    scala> def concat(first: String)(strs: String*) = first + strs.mkString
    concat: (first: String)(strs: String*)java.lang.String

    scala> val func = concat("NOK")_
    func: String* => java.lang.String = <function1>

Comment: Yes, it works in 2.9 but in Scala 2.10 support for function objects with varargs was removed.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  I am using scala 2.9.2, but I'll change the question so it accurately reflects the brave new world of scala 2.10.

Comment: `String* => String` is the very strange type. You can't pass it as parameter, so it's useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Scala 2.10 and shapeless:

```
import shapeless.Nat._
import shapeless.{Nat, Succ}

trait Curry[T, Res, N <: Nat] {
  type Out
  def apply(as: Seq[T], f : Seq[T] => Res) : Out
}

object Curry {
  implicit def curry[Out0, T, Res, N <: Nat](implicit curry : CurryAux[Out0, T, Res, N]) = new Curry[T, Res, N] {
    type Out = Out0
    def apply(as: Seq[T], f : Seq[T] => Res) = curry(as, f)
  }
}

trait CurryAux[Out, T, Res, N <: Nat] {
  def apply(as: Seq[T], f : Seq[T] => Res) : Out
}

object CurryAux {
  implicit def curry0[Res, T] = new CurryAux[Res, T, Res, _0] {
    def apply(as: Seq[T], f : Seq[T] => Res) : Res = f(as)
  }

  implicit def curryN[Out, T, Res, N <: Nat](implicit c : CurryAux[Out, T, Res, N]) =
    new CurryAux[T => Out, T, Res, Succ[N]] {
      def apply(as: Seq[T], f : Seq[T] => Res) : (T => Out) = (a: T) => c(as :+ a, f)
    }
}

implicit class CurryHelper[T, Res](f : Seq[T] => Res) {
  def curry[N <: Nat](implicit c : Curry[T, Res, N]): c.Out = c(IndexedSeq[T](), f)
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> def concat(strs: String*) = strs.mkString
concat: (strs: String*)String

scala> val test = ( concat _ ).curry[_3]
test: String => (String => (String => String)) = <function1>

scala> test("1")("2")("3")
res0: String = 123
```

Without shapeless:

```
class CurryHelper[T, Res](f: Seq[T] => Res, as: Seq[T]) {
  def myCurry() = this
  def apply(ts: T*) = new CurryHelper(f, as ++ ts)
  def apply(ts: Seq[T]) = f(as ++ ts)
}

implicit def toCurryHelper[T, Res](f: Seq[T] => Res) = new CurryHelper(f, IndexedSeq[T]())

scala> def concat(strs: String*) = strs.mkString
concat: (strs: String*)String

scala> val test = ( concat _ ).myCurry
test: CurryHelper[String,String] = CurryHelper@4f48ed35

scala> test("1")("2")("3", "4")(Nil)
res0: String = 1234
```