# Writing a function to curry any function

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

For the record I find it very annoying that functions are not automatically curried in Scala. I'm trying to write a factory that takes in any function and returns a curried version:

```
def curry(fn:(_ => _)) = (fn _).curried
```

Basically what I have defined here is a function `curry` that takes as an argument a function `fn` that is of type `_ => _` and returns a curried version of function `fn`. Obviously this didnt work because Java.

This was the error I got:

```
error: _ must follow method; cannot follow fn.type
       def curry(fn:(_ => _)) = (fn _).curried
```

Can any gurus out there help me figure out why this doesnt work? I don't mean to sound snarky, I am used to functional languages treating all types as functions. Please help this Scala newbie.

(I tagged this question with haskell because I'm trying to get Scala functions to behave like Haskell functions :'(

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, I need a `curryN` function, so a function that curries any other function regardless of its arity.

Side note, some people have pointed out that increasing the number of fn's arguments would solve the problem. Nope:

```
def curry2(fn:((_, _) => _)) = (fn _).curried
error: _ must follow method; cannot follow fn.type
       def curry2(fn:((_, _) => _)) = (fn _).curried
```

Comment: You can't `curry` a `Function1`.

Comment: please explain what that means

Comment: I don't know any Scala, but I reckon it means you need something like `curry(fn:((_,_) => _)) = (fn _).curried`.

Comment: `_ => _` is a `Function1`, `( _ , _ ) => _` is a `Function2` and so forth.

Comment: I need to curry a function that has N arguments. Thats what I was trying to describe... please see the update question

Comment: @BrianKent also, your answer doesnt compile. did you test it out before posting?

Comment: If you have a Function2 or higher then you can just call .curried

Comment: The wonky (f _) syntax is just to turn a method into a function.

Comment: So... if you read my update youll see that calling `curried` on a Function2 threw an error. What am I doing wrong? @BrianKent

Comment: Try doing fn.curried

Comment: How do I curry a function that has N arguments? @BrianKent

Answer (score 7):

Scala doesn't allow you to abstract over the arity of a function.  Thus, you need to use a typeclass-style approach (which allows you to abstract over just about anything, after you do all the manual work for it).

So, in particular, you do something like

```
sealed trait FunctionCurrier[Unc, Cur] { def apply(fn: Unc): Cur }
final class Function2Currier[A, B, Z]
extends FunctionCurrier[(A, B) => Z, A => B => Z] {
  def apply(fn: (A, B) => Z): (A => B => Z) = fn.curried
}
// Repeat for Function3 through Function21

implicit def makeCurrierForFunction2[A, B, Z]: Function2Currier[A, B, Z] =
  new Function2Currier[A, B, Z]
// Again, repeat for Function3 through Function21

def curryAll[Unc, Cur](fn: Unc)(implicit cf: FunctionCurrier[Unc, Cur]): Cur =
  cf(fn)
```

Now you can use it like so:

```
scala> def foo(a: Int, b: String) = a < b.length
foo: (a: Int, b: String)Boolean

scala> curryAll(foo _)
res0: Int => (String => Boolean) = <function1>
```

There is probably already something like this in Shapeless, but in this case you can roll your own, albeit with some tedium (and/or a code generator).

(Note: if you want to "curry" `A => Z`, you can write a `Function1Currier` that just returns the function untouched.)

Comment: this is... extremely verbose. Being a scala newbie can you clarify some things? What is a `sealed` trait? Why are some arguments in square brackets?

What is Shapeless?

Comment: You're trying to run before you can walk. If you really don't understand what type-parameters (the "arguments in square brackets") are, it's probably a bit premature to be trying to write a general function-currier. Shapeless: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Comment: @dopatraman - Paul's right.  You've asked to do something that isn't really newbie-accessible.  The newbie-level answer is: you can't, since Scala (like many languages) does not abstract over function arity (i.e. the number of parameters).  The actual answer is: you can write the abstracting code yourself if you know what you're doing.  Good incentive to move from being a newbie to not, even if it doesn't solve the problem you have right now!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `curried` method of functions.  You need to access the function itself as a partially applied function and get its curried form, like so:

```
def fn(i: Int, j: Int) = i + j

val fnCurryable = (fn _).curried

val fnCurried = fnCurryable(1)
println(fnCurried(2))
//prints 3
```

The same second line would work to curry any function with 2-22 arguments due to scala's powerful type inference.  Also, remember that you can declare your functions to be curryable in their declaration.  This would do the same as above:

```
def fnCurryable(i: Int)(j: Int) = i + j
```

The use of multiple argument lists means this function is called as `fnCurryable(1)(2)` and can NEVER be called as `fnCurryable(1, 2)`.  This conversion is basically what `.curried` does.
This is based on the function traits described on:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.package

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example? `fn` would be undefined here.

Comment: I need one function that returns a curried FunctionN. This is not that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def toCurry[A](f: (A, A) => A): A => A => A = x => f(x, _)
val addTwoNum = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y
val curriedAddTwoNum = toCurry(addTwoNum)
val part1Curry = curriedAddTwoNum(5)
println(part1Curry(2))
```

For additional arity, you would simply need to add additional params to the above function definition.

Otherwise, you may want to do something like [Can you curry a function with varargs in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778545/can-you-curry-a-function-with-varargs-in-scala)